# Oracle compare two different dates

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query cant execute from java . Here i use oracle xe server

```
datetrx <= to_date('2014-07-16 00:00:00.0','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss.f')
```

`datetrx` is in the date format of dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: "*datetrx is in the date format of dd/mm/yyyy*" - no it's not. A `date` column does **not have a format**. And "*cant execute from java*" is not an acceptable problem description.

Comment: Here the data type datetrx is date in the oracle xe . and that contain some data like  7/10/2014

Comment: Simply   i  just  want to compare '7/10/2014'  with  '2014-07-16 00:00:00.0'  in oracle . Here first one (7/10/2014) is from a column .

Answer (score 3):

Your input string in the `to_date()` function does not match your pattern. The value contains `-` as the delimiter, however in the pattern you use `/`:

If you align your input format and the pattern, this should work:

```
datetrx <= to_date('2014-07-16 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

I personally prefer ANSI timestamp literals over the `to_date()` function because they are portable and it's less typing:

```
datetrx <= timestamp '2014-07-16 00:00:00'
```

Note the format the string supplied here is *always* the ISO format.

---

A side note: 
Any "format" you see when looking at the values in the column `daterx` is applied by the SQL client you use to display that data (SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, ...).

The value itself is stored **without a format** on the server. Formatting of a `DATE` value is *always* done by the SQL client (or your application):

Comment: As I'm pretty sure you're already aware, you can't use fractional seconds with `to_date`, so you'd either end to drop the `.0` and `.f`; or use `to_timestamp` instead if the string can't be modified. But even then it would have to be `.ff`. (It's quite forgiving of `/` vs. `-` though; still better to get it right).

Comment: @AlexPoole: you are right. I just did copy & paste without thinking. Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

please specify your ask, its hard to figure out what do you want...
first of all this isnot a verified  date format

just type it and try it out with DUAL:

```
SELECT  to_date('2014-07-16 00:00:00.0', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.F') 
FROM dual;
```

delete the '.F' part from it

Comment: Sorry its giving .     * java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01821: date format not recognized

Comment: Simply   i  just  want to compare '7/10/2014'  with  '2014-07-16 00:00:00.0'  in oracle . Here first one (7/10/2014) is from a column .

Comment: yes i see, and as i mentioned before you need to fix your date pattern, because does not exist such pattern like that with the '.f' in Oracle. it's not because of the delimiters e.g. '/' or '-', its irrelevant -> see : select CASE WHEN to_date('2014-07-16 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= to_date('2014/07/16', 'YYYY/MM/DD') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM dual;

Comment: the error ORA-01821: date format not recognized because there is no pattern like 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.F' in oracle, ok? :)