# Wrong Date difference

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a function (daysBetween)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION daysBetween
(
    p_date1  DATE,
    p_date2  DATE
)
     RETURN NUMBER
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (TRUNC(p_date1) - TRUNC(p_date2));
END;
```

**With this function i have query**

```
SELECT   COALESCE(daysBetween(to_date('11-07-2003','mm-dd-yyyy'),
         to_date(datetrx,'mm-dd-yyyy')),0) 
from payment;
```

The result is wrong.it is showing wrong difference.

Comment: What data are you testing with, what result do you expect (and why), and what do you actually get? What data type is `datetrx` - date or varchar2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24774316/266304) you said `datetrx` is a `DATE`, so you should not be using it as an argument to `to_date()`. You're doing an implicit conversion to a string, and then an explicit conversion back. From that question it looks like your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `dd/mm/yyyy`. So you're really doing this for the second argument passed to the function:

```
to_date(to_char(datetrx, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'mm-dd-yyyy')
```

As long as day part of the `datetrx` value is <= 12 this will appear to work but will give you a different date than you started with - as you're swapping the day and month values over. That may be why you're getting the wrong answer from the function. If the day was later than the 12th of the month then it would error though.

But you don't need to convert it at all, just do:

```
SELECT COALESCE(daysBetween(to_date('11-07-2003', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), datetrx), 0) 
from payment;
```

Or using ANSI syntax as suggested before:

```
SELECT COALESCE(daysBetween(date '2003-11-07', datetrx), 0) 
from payment;
```

It's also possible you wanted to compare against July 11th rather then November 7th, which would give you the wrong result even if your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is actually `mm/dd/yyyy`. Impossible to tell without any sample data and expected and actual results.